# How to left-align a video?

Tags: html

I have a Shopify website. I put these lines of code into my product description and I cannot left-align the video.

```html
<div style="text-align: left;">
  <video width="100%" height="270" playsinline="" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/7956/1398/files/NUMBER_11.mp4?v=1626331670" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="">
  </video>
</div>
```

[image: Image to show what I mean]

I have zero programming knowledge.

Comment: Remove `width` & `height` attributes from the `video` tag

Comment: Hey @Shuvo thanks for the quick reply. Where else would I put the attributes? Under the <div> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of width="100%" for video

Comment: When I get rid of width="100%" the video becomes messed up on the mobile version. For some reason width="100%" makes the video fit the screen perfectly, but if I remove it the image becomes too big that I can't even see the whole thing on the screen(on mobile).

Comment: If you are aware of aspect ratio, you can give width and height in the same ratio.